# Enabling Kerberos on Hadoop throws "java.io.IOException: Server asks us to fall back to SIMPLE auth.."

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, kerberos

I have configured Kerberos on **AWS EMR** and it shows successful configuration for hdfs as well as hadoop user.

However issuing "hdfs dfs -ls" command throws error:
*"java.io.IOException: Server asks us to fall back to SIMPLE auth, but this client is configured to only allow secure connections."*

On Kerberos Client:

-bash-4.2$ kinit
Password for hdfs@MYCLUSTER.COM:

-bash-4.2$ klist -k -t /etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs.keytab
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs.keytab
KVNO Timestamp           Principal

---

3 05/14/2017 00:14:04 hdfs@MYCLUSTER.COM
   3 05/14/2017 00:14:04 hdfs@MYCLUSTER.COM

I checked both KDC server and Client are in sync in terms of NTP (no time skew observed).

I enabled Debugging and here is the snippet from the logs:

```
[root@ip-172-31-49-79 etc]# HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=DEBUG,console hdfs dfs -ls /
17/05/14 02:12:22 DEBUG util.Shell: setsid exited with exit code 0
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG conf.Configuration: parsing URL jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.7.3-amzn-2.jar!/core-default.xml
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG conf.Configuration: parsing input stream sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@25359ed8
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG conf.Configuration: parsing URL file:/etc/hadoop/conf.empty/core-site.xml
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG conf.Configuration: parsing input stream java.io.BufferedInputStream@6f3b5d16
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginSuccess with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(about=, sampleName=Ops, always=false, type=DEFAULT, valueName=Time, value=[Rate of successful kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)])
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginFailure with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(about=, sampleName=Ops, always=false, type=DEFAULT, valueName=Time, value=[Rate of failed kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)])
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG lib.MutableMetricsFactory: field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.getGroups with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(about=, sampleName=Ops, always=false, type=DEFAULT, valueName=Time, value=[GetGroups])
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG impl.MetricsSystemImpl: UgiMetrics, User and group related metrics
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG security.Groups:  Creating new Groups object
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG util.NativeCodeLoader: Trying to load the custom-built native-hadoop library...
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping: Using JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping for Group resolution
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback: Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG security.Groups: Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback; cacheTimeout=300000; warningDeltaMs=5000
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: hadoop login
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: hadoop login commit
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: using kerberos user:null
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: using local user:UnixPrincipal: root
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: Using user: "UnixPrincipal: root" with name root
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: User entry: "root"
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: UGI loginUser:root (auth:KERBEROS)
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG hdfs.BlockReaderLocal: dfs.client.use.legacy.blockreader.local = false
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG hdfs.BlockReaderLocal: dfs.client.read.shortcircuit = false
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG hdfs.BlockReaderLocal: dfs.client.domain.socket.data.traffic = false
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG hdfs.BlockReaderLocal: dfs.domain.socket.path =
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG retry.RetryUtils: multipleLinearRandomRetry = null
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG ipc.Server: rpcKind=RPC_PROTOCOL_BUFFER, rpcRequestWrapperClass=class org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$RpcRequestWrapper, rpcInvoker=org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker@6b58b9e9
17/05/14 02:12:23 DEBUG ipc.Client: getting client out of cache: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@4167d97b
17/05/14 02:12:24 DEBUG azure.NativeAzureFileSystem: finalize() called.
17/05/14 02:12:24 DEBUG azure.NativeAzureFileSystem: finalize() called.
17/05/14 02:12:24 DEBUG unix.DomainSocketWatcher: org.apache.hadoop.net.unix.DomainSocketWatcher$2@3213a316: starting with interruptCheckPeriodMs = 60000
17/05/14 02:12:24 DEBUG util.PerformanceAdvisory: Both short-circuit local reads and UNIX domain socket are disabled.
17/05/14 02:12:24 DEBUG sasl.DataTransferSaslUtil: DataTransferProtocol not using SaslPropertiesResolver, no QOP found in configuration for dfs.data.transfer.protection
17/05/14 02:12:24 DEBUG ipc.Client: The ping interval is 60000 ms.
17/05/14 02:12:24 DEBUG ipc.Client: Connecting to ip-172-31-49-79.ec2.internal/172.31.49.79:8020
17/05/14 02:12:24 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction as:root (auth:KERBEROS) from:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:725)
17/05/14 02:12:24 DEBUG security.SaslRpcClient: Sending sasl message state: NEGOTIATE

17/05/14 02:12:24 DEBUG security.SaslRpcClient: Received SASL message state: NEGOTIATE
auths {
  method: "TOKEN"
  mechanism: "DIGEST-MD5"
  protocol: ""
  serverId: "default"
  challenge: "realm=\"default\",nonce=\"b44IiskXjHckOO9qu4sNJ6Dm7lqzWmH+iyShWzt4\",qop=\"auth\",charset=utf-8,algorithm=md5-sess"
}
auths {
  method: "SIMPLE"
  mechanism: ""
}

17/05/14 02:12:24 DEBUG security.SaslRpcClient: Get token info proto:interface org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolPB info:@org.apache.hadoop.security.token.TokenInfo(value=class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.security.token.delegation.DelegationTokenSelector)
17/05/14 02:12:24 DEBUG security.SaslRpcClient: Use SIMPLE authentication for protocol ClientNamenodeProtocolPB
17/05/14 02:12:24 DEBUG security.SaslRpcClient: Sending sasl message state: INITIATE
auths {
  method: "SIMPLE"
  mechanism: ""
}

17/05/14 02:12:24 DEBUG ipc.Client: closing ipc connection to ip-172-31-49-79.ec2.internal/172.31.49.79:8020: Server asks us to fall back to SIMPLE auth, but this client is configured to only allow secure connections.
java.io.IOException: Server asks us to fall back to SIMPLE auth, but this client is configured to only allow secure connections.
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:754)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1451)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1713)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.PathData.expandAsGlob(PathData.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArgument(Command.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArguments(Command.java:218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processRawArguments(Command.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:340)
17/05/14 02:12:24 DEBUG ipc.Client: IPC Client (735937428) connection to ip-172-31-49-79.ec2.internal/172.31.49.79:8020 from root: closed
ls: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Server asks us to fall back to SIMPLE auth, but this client is configured to only allow secure connections.; Host Details : local host is: "ip-172-31-49-79.ec2.internal/172.31.49.79"; destination host is: "ip-172-31-49-79.ec2.internal":8020;
17/05/14 02:12:24 DEBUG ipc.Client: stopping client from cache: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@4167d97b
17/05/14 02:12:24 DEBUG ipc.Client: removing client from cache: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@4167d97b
17/05/14 02:12:24 DEBUG ipc.Client: stopping actual client because no more references remain: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@4167d97b
17/05/14 02:12:24 DEBUG ipc.Client: Stopping client
```

Comment: Taken *verbatim*, that error message means the NameNode does not run in Kerberos mode... So what do you see in the NameNode logs? About that connection attempt, but also about Kerberos ticket creation (at service start-up) and renewals (at every 80% of "lifetime" of the previous ticket)?

Comment: core-site.xml from NN:                                                             
  <configuration>

  <property>
    <!-- URI of NN. Fully qualified. No IP.-->
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://ip-172-31-49-79.ec2.internal:8020</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
    <value>kerberos</value>
  </property>

Comment: Namenode in my cluster :                                                                        
bash-4.2$ hdfs getconf -nameNodes
ip-172-31-49-79.ec2.internal

Comment: _"NameNode logs"_ = logs of the NameNode service.

Comment: bash-4.2$ hdfs getconf -nameNodes
ip-172-31-49-79.ec2.internal

bash-4.2$ kinit
Password for hdfs@EC2.INTERNAL:
bash-4.2$ klist
Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:494:494
Default principal: hdfs@EC2.INTERNAL
Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
05/16/2017 14:58:42  05/17/2017 14:58:42  krbtgt/EC2.INTERNAL@EC2.INTERNAL

Comment: bash-4.2$ hdfs dfs -ls /usr
ls: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Server asks us to fall back to SIMPLE auth, but this client is configured to only allow secure connections.; Host Details : local host is: "ip-172-31-49-79/172.31.49.79"; destination host is: "ip-172-31-49-79.ec2.internal":8020;

Checking namenode logs :

2017-05-16 14:02:55,744 INFO com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.metrics2.sink.cloudwatch.CloudWatchSink (cloudwatch): Metrics pushed
2017-05-16 14:07:55,748 INFO com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.metrics2.sink.cloudwatch.CloudWatchSink (cloudwatch): Metrics pushed

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter : I am newbie to kerberos and would greatly appreciate if you can guide me. Any help would be huge bonus for me.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter: Thanks. Here is the excerpt from namenode.log: 017-05-17 16:02:55,743 INFO com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.metrics2.sink.cloudwatch.CloudWatchSink (cloudwatch): Metrics pushed
2017-05-17 16:07:55,743 INFO com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.metrics2.sink.cloudwatch.CloudWatchSink (cloudwatch): Metrics pushed
2017-05-17 16:12:55,743 INFO com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.metrics2.sink.cloudwatch.CloudWatchSink (cloudwatch): Metrics pushed
2017-05-17 16:17:55,746 INFO com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.metrics2.sink.cloudwatch.CloudWatchSink (cloudwatch): Metrics pushed

Comment: Namenode log name : hadoop-hdfs-namenode-ip-172-31-49-79.log

Comment: Nothing about authentication errors, in an audit log? Nothing about Kerberos when you `grep` the log files?